# MATLAB - Make table from for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, matlab-table

I have the following code

```
x=[1 0.5 0.5]', iter=0; dxnorm=1;
while dxnorm>0.5e-4 & iter<10
    f=[cos(x(1))+cos(x(2))+cos(x(3))-2
        sin(x(1))+sin(x(2))+sin(x(3))
        tan(x(1))-2.*tan(x(2))+tan(x(3))
        ]                          ;
    J=[-sin(x(1))     -sin(x(2))      -sin(x(3))
        cos(x(1))      cos(x(2))      cos(x(3))
        tan(x(1)).^2 + 1    -2*tan(x(2)).^2 - 2     tan(x(3)).^2 + 1];
    dx=-J\f;
    x=x+dx;
    dxnorm = norm(dx,inf), iter=iter+1;
end
x, iter
```

and I would like to store the results after every iteration in a table so I can see how the result changes as the time goes on. I have seen some different codes on how to do this (that is, you have a for loop, and store every result in a table) but none that I have been able to implement. Any ideas how I could do this? For example, I did watch some examples from here, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/163572-creating-a-table-of-values-from-for-loops but as I said wasn't able to implement any of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an iterator to store the results during each iteration of the loop. If you want to save `x` and `dxnorm`, for example, you could store them in columns of a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) and not worry about them being different sizes.

```
x = [1 0.5 0.5]';
maxiter = 10;
iter = 0;
dxnorm = 1;
results = cell(maxiter + 1, 2); % Preallocate results array

while dxnorm > 0.5e-4 && iter <= maxiter
    f = [cos(x(1)) + cos(x(2))    + cos(x(3))-2; ...
         sin(x(1)) + sin(x(2))    + sin(x(3)); ...
         tan(x(1)) - 2.*tan(x(2)) + tan(x(3)); ...
         ];
    J = [-sin(x(1)),       -sin(x(2)),          -sin(x(3)); ...
         cos(x(1)),        cos(x(2)),           cos(x(3)); ...
         tan(x(1)).^2 + 1, -2*tan(x(2)).^2 - 2, tan(x(3)).^2 + 1 ...
         ];
    dx = -J\f;
    results{iter + 1, 1} = x;
    x = x + dx;
    dxnorm = norm(dx,inf);
    results{iter + 1, 2} = dxnorm;
    iter = iter + 1;
end
```

This gives you a cell array `results`, where the first column contains your `x` data and the second column contains your `dxnorm` data for each loop iteration. You index into the cell of a cell arrays [using curly braces `{}`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html), e.g. `results{1, 1}` gives you the `x` data used for the first iteration of your loop.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. Just wanted a neat way to store data and this was it. I have always liked to organize ;)